# Worker Role not creating model object?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I've gotten my worker role to ...work. Now i'm having one more minor issue.

My worker role access SQL Azure through the Entity Framework. I'm tring to create a list of populated Email objects from my database and then send those emails. The code works fine locally, but throws exceptions when deployed in the cloud.

To Clarfiy: The worker role IS in a 'Ready' State and when it reaches the problematic piece of code, it causes an excpetion and breaks into a catch block and continues to execute code.

It's only when I try to create my email object:

eg.

Entities entities = new Entities(); //Entities being the name of my DB Model

List emailList = entities.Email.where(x => x.sent == 0).toList(); //creating my list of entities

I've been looking through the intellitrace logs from the Azure deployment (in vs2010) and I'm noticing that I'm getting a "System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types" when my worker role attempts to populate a list with the above code. Looking at the call stack, it points to the Email Model.

I have my webrole working perfectly when deployed with the same code.In addition, I include a referance to my web role in my worker role and it's copy local property IS set to true.

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 1):

One of the common problems with Azure is that the **deployment does not copy some dlls unless they are marked with "CopyLocal"** within the Worker Role and/or Web Role. All Dlls absent from GAC of Azure OS should be present.

[Article with more details](http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/02/windows-azure-deployment-did-you-forget-to-pack-your-dlls.html)

I've been bitten by that a couple of times myself.